# Input Assistant screen location issue

Tags: input

I most often run a THREE monitor configuration from a Dell laptop. When I am editing a notebook on the monitor identified as #3 by Windows 11, the Autocomplete suggestions and other popups like coordinates from a selected ListPlot (via "Get Coordinates" menu item) appear on monitor #1. This is very odd and does not occur when the notebook is located on the other two monitors.

This is more than a nuisance and I am starting to get whiplash.

Anyone else seen this issue?

[image]

Comment: This sounds like a question for WRI (support@wolfram.com). I doubt that people here will be able to help much

Comment: For sure just providing information to the community.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: 13.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (August 14, 2022)

Comment: I remember of bug involving a similar monitor layout that should have been fixed in 13.2.  I would give that a shot.